# Locking statement won't compile with INNER JOIN present

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, locking, syntax-error

I'm writing a stored proc in SQL Server 2008. The following code:

```
SELECT      @LastAccessed = cs.LastAccessed
FROM        [int].ClientSessions AS cs INNER JOIN
            dbo.Profiles AS p ON cs.ProfileID = p.ProfileID
WITH        (XLOCK, ROWLOCK)
WHERE       (p.ClientID = @ClientID)
```

...won't compile, stating a syntax error at XLOCK.

If I remove the INNER JOIN statement (which is impossible because I need the join), then it's fine with the XLOCK. I don't see what the issue is.

Note: I only want to lock the [int].ClientSessions table, so I realize this may not be the best approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put the `WITH (XLOCK, ROWLOCK)` after the `as cs`/ `as p` statement.

Something like

```
SELECT      @LastAccessed = cs.LastAccessed 
FROM        [int].ClientSessions AS cs WITH (XLOCK, ROWLOCK) INNER JOIN 
            dbo.Profiles AS p ON cs.ProfileID = p.ProfileID 
WHERE       (p.ClientID = @ClientID)
```

Have a look at [Table Hints (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx)

Comment: Wow, that wasn't in my guess list. Thanks.

Comment: I assume the 2nd WITH is a typo. I got it to compile with the following: SELECT  @LastAccessed = cs.LastAccessed
 FROM  [int].ClientSessions AS cs INNER JOIN
    dbo.Profiles AS p 
 WITH  (XLOCK, ROWLOCK)
    ON cs.ProfileID = p.ProfileID
 WHERE  (p.ClientID = @ClientID)